# Android Binder Leaks

Tags: android, service

I just read http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android about how there can be memory leaks when binding to a local service...

I am currently implementing binding to a local service using the following code.

In the service I have:

```
private final Binder binder=new LocalBinder();
public class LocalBinder extends Binder implements IStreamCommander {
        public void registerPlayer(IStreamListener callback) {
            theUI=callback;
        }

        public void removePlayer(IStreamListener callback) {
            theUI=null;
        }

        public void play(Station NowP) {
            playURL(NowP);
        }

        public void stop() {
            stopIt();
        }
    }
```

Where IStreamCommander is defined:

```
public interface IStreamCommander {
 void registerPlayer(IStreamListener callback);
 void removePlayer(IStreamListener callback);
 void play(Station SongID);
 void stop();
}
```

and IStreamListener is defined:

```
public interface IStreamListener {
 void updateUI(String msg, int buttons);
}
```

I then have this in the activity:

```
this.bindService(startedSvc, svcConn, 0);
```

and

```
private ServiceConnection svcConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        service = (IStreamCommander) binder;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        service = null;
    }
};
```

So am I leaking memory, or is this okay?

Comment: i followed this link and change all my service and use the same binder  http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android but when i run the MAT tool still i can see the binder object exist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are going to stick with the binding pattern, I would:

- Move your `Binder` to a standalone public class, not an inner class
- Bind using `getApplicationContext()`, rather than `this`
- Make sure you use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` properly to pass your binding between instances of your activity when the configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation)

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI) demonstrating this.